# When I add a time to my jsquery calendar it is changing to a different time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Sorry if this has already been fully answered but I can’t pin down the actual solution to my problem.

I think this should be a simple solution and I’m pretty sure I know the problem, however, I’m hoping to get a well informed final decision on what the best way to handle this problem is.

So.. my server is physically in Arizona, USA but I am in the UK and so are all my users. I’m using Jquery FullCalendar to store events on my site. When I input a time (using Bootstrap DateTime Picker) on my site it is adding 8hours to the time and displaying eg. 6.00pm when 10.00am has been input.

However, when I add a time on my actual server it inputs the correct time and displays correctly, but then displays on the UK based client machine with the additional 8hours.

My question is, do I need to minus/subtract 8hours before I let it update the time within my SQL Db? Or should I be tweaking the settings somewhere else? Is there a way to change the time of the Server or should I be handling this issue with code?

I imagine this is a proper noob question so apologies in advance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it is adding 8hours"...what is adding? The browser, or the server? Short answer is you need to deal with timezones. Arizona is (currently) 8 hours behind the UK (but that might change when the UK moves out of DST). Decide which timezone you're going to store the data in (either the local time of the server, or UTC time would be sensible choices), and then make sure that when you _display_ the data to the user, it uses their local timezone. Without seeing any code or setup info, it's hard to give any more specific advice than that.

Comment: fullCalendar and momentJS both include mechanisms for working with different timezones and locales, and understand time strings expressed with zonal information. SQL Server can also do the same. If you haven't worked with timezones before, it can be confusing, so do a bit more research yourself before continuing. However another option, if all your users are in one timezone, is to simply store and display everything in a single timezone (e.g. UTC) and pretend the whole problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok thanks ADyson, I thought that this might be the problem. I’ll search for some code to handle the different time zones and let you know how I get on. I will also post some code/examples later today. Apologies for the poorly written question, I had gone a bit nuts by the time I was posting on here yesterday.